# Passing a PHP variable into Javascript adds a 1 onto the end instead of adding to the sum

Tags: javascript, php

Just a quick background... I run a little website view exchange and I'm currently trying to have the total count of website views (by the members) displayed on the front page and update every second. Instead of querying the database every second my plan is to grab the initial total page views on load then have the average view per second added to the output using javascript. It almost works... except every second a '1' character is placed next to the query instead of added into the total. Its kind of amusing... and if I'm not explaining it well here's the page I'm testing it on.
http://vinrasta.com/?_n=test

Here's the code isolated in jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/thknue5b/

```
var totalHits = "<?php echo $row[0]; ?>";
window.setInterval(
    function () {
    totalHits = totalHits + 1;
    document.getElementById("surfOutput").innerHTML = "Currently " + totalHits + " surfed!";
}, 1000);
```

Thanks in advance for your help! I appreciate your time.

Comment: you are passing "<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" as a string , so when you add 1 you add 1 as a char and not as a number. Try to use var totalHits = parseInt(something);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do `parseInt(totalHits) + 1` to convert totalHits from string to int:

```
var totalHits = "2";
window.setInterval(
function () {
console.log(totalHits);
    totalHits = parseInt(totalHits) + 1;
    document.getElementById("surfOutput").innerHTML = "Currently " + totalHits + " surfed!";
}, 1000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/thknue5b/4/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! After adding  totalHits = totalHits.replace(/,/g, "");  This solution worked perfectly. Thanks again!